# VSphere windows VM Cycle restarting

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2, vsphere

I've faced with a strange VM behaviour

**What do we have:**
-VSphere vm
-Windows 2008 R2

**Problem:**
Vm restarting after few moments after start. When the "press ctrl-alt-del for log in" screen appears after few moments later vm restarts, I can log in and see the desktop but it will be restarted anyway.
The only way to boot it - press F8 and choose "Last known good configuration"

**what have i tried to do**
- deleted all devices except memory, CPUs, Video card, VMCI Device, SCSI controller and hard disc
- Switched off reboot when system crach (in registry and in F8 menu).

Help. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got it.
After reading [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/be2b9527-e266-4f59-ab36-bc3190aca078/server-2008-r2-wont-boot?forum=winservergen) thread i've started to switching off all of services on server.

The cause of cycle rebooting was very old self-developed service. I switched it off and Vm stop its reboot cycle.